# Class with non-default constructor, within a class (C++)

Tags: c++, class, constructor

I have a class which takes two arguments on it's constructor, an *int* and a *void(*)(void)* so normally when I need to call it I do it like this:

```
obj_child (int_value, pointer_to_foo);
```

Now what I want is to instantiate the *obj_child*  with constant arguments, within another class.

So I tried:

```
class obj_parent
{

    private:

        obj_child child_instantiation (int_value, pointer_to_foo);

};
```

but this seems to give me two compiler errors on the line I declare *child_instantiation* so I guess the arguments can't be passed there but somewhere else.

Mind you *child_instantiation*s are supposed to have the same arguments for all *obj_parent* instantiations, so they shouldn't be passed as *obj_parent* constructor arguments.

Declaring the class pointer and then creating a new one on the heap compiles, but I don't want to do it that way and I don't know if it works (my debugger can't watch the reference so it's very hard to monitor it's values).

```
class obj_parent
    {

        private:

            obj_child *child_instantiation;

    };

obj_parent::
obj_parent (void)
{

    child_instantiation = new obj_child child_instantiation (int_value, pointer_to_foo);


}
```

Thanks!

(Please don't mind the semantics, child - parent has nothing to do with inheritance, just couldn't think better names right now)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to initialize the object in the constructor of the class.

```
obj_parent() : child_instantiation (int_value, pointer_to_foo) {}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you'd do it

```
// note that this class has no constructor with 0 args
class PrimaryClass {
  public:
    PrimaryClass(int arg1, void* arg2) {
      // do something here
    }
};

class SecondaryClass {
  private:
    PrimaryClass my_obj;
  public:
    // We call the constructor to my_obj here (using initialization lists)
    SecondaryClass(int arg1, void* arg2) : my_obj(arg1, arg2) {
      // other stuff here, maybe
    }
};
```